# How do I upgrade python3.8 to python3.9 and install docker using cloud-init on Azure VM's ubuntu?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, cloud-init

I have followed the tutorial listed in Azure's official documentation. [Automate VM Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-automate-vm-deployment)

Here are the steps I followed in Azure's official tutorial.

1. Creating a yaml file below

```
## Install packages on first boot
package_upgrade: true
packages:
  - docker
  - nodejs
  - python3.9
```

2. Pasting the contents of cloud-config in the cloud init when I create a Ubuntu instance.

When I tried checking the Python version, it was still Python3.8 and also I could not invoke `docker`. When I checked the `/var/log/cloud-init.log`, docker has been successfully installed.

Log of `less /var/log/cloud-init.log`

```
2021-12-10 06:03:55,535 - subp.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['eatmydata', 'apt-get', '--option=Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold', '--option=Dpkg::options::=--force-unsafe-
io', '--assume-yes', '--quiet', 'install', 'docker'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=False)
2021-12-10 06:03:57,901 - util.py[DEBUG]: apt-install [eatmydata apt-get --option=Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold --option=Dpkg::options::=--force-unsafe-io --assume-ye
s --quiet install docker] took 2.365 seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It was still Python3.8

How did you invoke python? Installing python3.9 won't replace the system libraries or python. So `python3` will still point to python3.8, but you should be able to invoke python3.9 with `python3.9`.

- I could not invoke docker

I think you intended to install `docker.io`, not `docker`. `docker` in the repos is a system tray docking application.

Comment: I have successfully installed docker with docker.io.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to install python3.9 and invoked it with runcmd. What is the difference of installing packages with runcmd and packages?

https://gist.github.com/ahlag/293287b4ba1711657455e17e9a97b9e2

Comment: I have also found a way to install docker from an APT source. What is the best practice of installing packages?

[Reference]
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418815/how-do-i-install-docker-using-cloud-init